# moment.js is ignoring locale setting while formatting date to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs, datetime-format

I have a UTC Date and convert it with moment.js in node.js to my local timezone 'de' GMT+2. Everything works fine except converting to unix timestamp.

The output of timestamp is 2018-08-01 09:54:02 but unixTimestamp is 1533110042 which is converted 08/01/2018 @ **7:54am** (UTC) (converted on https://www.unixtimestamp.com)

I lost my +2 hours.

Is this normal?

```js
moment.locale('de');

var date = '2018-08-01T07:54:02.000Z';

var timestamp = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var unixTimestamp = moment(date).format('X');

console.log('date :', date);
console.log('timestamp :', timestamp);
console.log('unixTimestamp :', unixTimestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Has anybody an idea why this is?

Comment: What's the issue here? I can see the timestamp value correctly in the results. Did you try running the snippet?

Comment: time stamp is denoted in milliseconds. what you see is correct

Comment: yes i know but if u convert the timestamp back to human readable date it is without +2 hours (in my location)

Comment: A Unix timestamp does not carry time zone information by design. It's always in UTC.

Comment: ahhh realy, i didnt know that. Good to know, thank u!